# Should we introduce a new tag for qgis + Sextante?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Since the latest stable of QGIS (2.0 Dufour) the toolbox previously known as Sextante has been included in QGIS. It is now known simply as processing toolbox.

Right now most people still know the new processing toolbox with its original name sextante but this might change in the future. The tag combination qgis+sextante might become obsolete in this process.

As Sextante is also beeing used in combinations with other GIS software (like OpenJump), we should somehow tag questions with `sextante` differently in relation with `qgis`.

Maybe like [qgis-processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-processing) or [processing-toolbox](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/processing-toolbox)?
Is there already a need to talk about this?

Comment: +1 This seems like a timely discussion

Comment: qgis-processing seems best

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks Curlew! I think now is exactly the right time to talk about this. From my point of view, I think qgis-processing would be a better choice than processing-toolbox since the toolbox is only one feature of the whole processing (mhm, "framework"?). I'd suggest to start correcting tags for all new questions and the old ones which already concern QGIS 2.0 with processing.

Comment: for the old ones: Maybe its also time for an introduction of a `qgis-2.0` tag?

Comment: @Curlew: Again, I don't think so. Perhaps qgis-2 if you want to distinguish versions, but anything that applies to 2.0 will probably apply to 2.1.

Comment: Tags should not be changed or "corrected" unless they are truly erroneous. Consider creating a synonym for [tag:sextante]. That's much less work, does not change the tags already applied, and has the desired effect.

Comment: @underdark -- Not sure if i'm too late to comment, but: Surely, the new/changed tag should be  [qgis-sextante] and _not_  [sextante-qgis]. That allows me to include/exclude [qgis*] from searches. Or am i off the mark, ie, is qgis actually a sub-topic of sextante?

Comment: @martinf sextante has been renamed to processing, so should be [qgis-processing] now

Comment: Ooh, thanks for quick response! So what do we do about existing  sextante tags?

Comment: @martinf nothing. when those were asked, the tool was still called sextante. those questions probably only have historical value anyway since quite a lot has been changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

The Question titled **[How to sum up all field values in QGIS modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74020/how-to-sum-up-all-field-values-in-qgis-modeler)** is tagged [modelbuilder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modelbuilder) but does not discuss the ModelBuilder component from ArcGIS for Desktop.

Consequently, it would appear to strengthen the case for creation of a tag for the QGIS equivalent to ModelBuilder.

I do not know the QGIS components very well but maybe there should be a [qgis-modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-modeler) tag.

Would that perhaps be a more recognisable term than [qgis-processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-processing)?

Comment: Although qgis-processing is the official name (Processing toolbox), i actually like qgis-modeler better

Answer (score -2):

I don't think we should have an extra tag. For many users, that toolbox is just part of QGIS now. How it got there, or its old name(s), don't matter. If we need to have a "finer granularity" on QGIS questions, perhaps something that is more meaningful to the user. I'm not sure what though (perhaps qgis-vector / qgis-raster, but that seems a bit forced too).

Comment: I strongly disagree with your point. In ArcGIS for example, it's quite important if you run a GPtool  from the ArcToolbox or whether you use one of the commands in the toolbars to do something; Similarly there would be differences between the tools in qgis-processing and something else. The issue becomes clearer if we use the actual name of the thing, rather than arbitrarily calling it something that we think it should be called. This requires that the QGIS team name it properly, and use the name in documentation etc.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I hadn't realised that there were so many arctoolbox questions (albeit, a few people asking many similar questions).