# Should we reorganize sextante, sextante-qgis-plugin, and qgis-processing tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I'm aware of [Should we introduce a new tag for qgis + Sextante?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/should-we-introduce-a-new-tag-for-qgis-sextante), but it doesn't seem to have had a complete implementation, even though it is tagged as [status-completed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed).

You may know that the processing framework SEXTANTE was implemented in several GIS software such as gvSIG, gvSIG CE, ArcGIS, QGIS, and even 52n-WPS. The current description of [sextante](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sextante) tag doesn't reflect such diversity.

Furthermore, [sextante](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sextante) has a synonym called [sextante-qgis-plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sextante-qgis-plugin).

There is also the [qgis-processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-processing) tag, which must be preferred for the former SEXTANTE (now Processing) plugin in QGIS.

Do you have any suggestion to improve this?

I've posted an answer with my proposal.

Comment: Synonyms don't have descriptions - they point back at their Master tags, so what you're seeing is the description/Wiki for the Master (ie, click on sextante-qgis-plugin and what you actually see is the list of questions tagged sextante with that tag's Wiki excerpt/description and links). Synonyms can be broken, which is the distinction between a synonym and a tag merge PolyGeo was talking about earlier. Here, you should probably make your suggestion an answer rather than part of the question. That way it can be voted on as compared to any other suggested solutions (should there be any).

Comment: I see. Edited the part of the shared descriptions.

Comment: I agree both with what you describe in the question and what @ChrisW speaks about procedurally; and recommend that you cut some of your text into an answer to conform to our [Guideline for proposing tag synonyms](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3820/guidelines-for-proposing-tag-synonyms).

Comment: Ok, it's posted!

Comment: The voting seemed very clearly in favour of breaking the synonymy between [tag:sextante] and [tag:sextante-qgis-plugin], and making the latter a synonym of [tag:qgis-processing], so both have now been done using the moderator tools.  I'll leave it to the community to check/revise the wiki entries, and perform any retags that may now be necessary.  Many thanks for taking the time to document what was needed here.

Answer (score 6):

In order to improve this situation, I suggest to:

- Remove the synonym relation between [sextante](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sextante) and [sextante-qgis-plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sextante-qgis-plugin) which will need a moderator action.
- Modify the [sextante](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sextante) wiki description so that it refers to the generic SEXTANTE processing framework.
- Make [sextante-qgis-plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sextante-qgis-plugin) a synonym of [qgis-processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-processing), the latter being the master.

I think this could help clarify the posts involved.

Comment: Today, after some additional disambiguation of the [tag:processing] tag, I made that a synonym of [tag:qgis-processing] too.  About 50-60 of the 70 questions tagged [tag:processing] were clearly related to QGIS.